# MS ACCESS Multiple Record Visibility If Statement

Tags: ms-access, vba, visibility

I am building a form in Access 2013 and I will print out 4 fields for each record.

So Let's say the form processes 2 records it will print out:

```
Field 1   Field 2   Field 3  Field 4
Field 1   Field 2   Field 3  Field 4
```

Now I want to have it when it displays Other to print out the description of the other from a table.  To do this I want the field named DefectType to go invisible and then the Other field to become visible.  I start with Other being invisible and DefectType Visible and place them on top of each other.  Here is the VBA:

```
If DefectType <> "Other" Then
DefectType.Visible = True
Other.Visible = False
Else
DefectType.Visible = False
Other.Visible = True
End If
```

It works fine if they are all other because what it does it takes the first record value of Other and applies it to all the other records for that field.

So if the first record that is displayed has a field 3 and it has a value of Other it will then look for the value in the table that is under the "other" field and display the content.  SO lets say the "other" content was lamination.  Instead of showing Other it will make that DefectType field invisible and show the "Other" field which will show Lamination.
The problem is it then does this for the rest of the records.  It won't test to see if the field 3 is "Other" or not, it will just assume and then put it's "Other" field contents for the subsequent records.  This means that since some actually already have values in them, like Corrosion, and nothing in the "other" field it will display a blank box.

I want it to test each field 3 as it is displayed so it can tell if "other" is in the field or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure how well I understand your question, but it sounds to me that your form includes 2 text boxes named *DefectType* and *Other*.  When the value of *DefectType* is *"Other"*, you want to display the value from the *Other* text box.  But when the value of *DefectType* is anything else, you want to display the value of *DefectType*.

If that is correct, you can create a new text box named *txtSummary* and use this as its Control Source property.

```vb
=IIf([DefectType] = "Other", [Other], [DefectType])
```

The *txtSummary* text box would not be editable.  To change its value, you would change the values in *DefectType* and/or *Other*.

That approach will ensure *txtSummary* is always updated based on the current values of *DefectType* and *Other* in the same record.  And it will do that for each record in the form, including when the form is in Continuous Form or DataSheet View.

Your original approach would do what I think you want only when the form is in Single Form view.